# If the ISS hull were ferromagnetic what kinds of problems would that cause?

Tags: iss, spacecraft, magnetic-field

The question [ISS Electromagnetic anchoring](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18528/12102) asks if the hull of the ISS were ferromagnetic, which would allow astronauts on EVAs to use magnetic grapples to assist in moving around.

The answer [sadly, no](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18536/12102) made me wonder if perhaps there might might be *an up side* to the hull being non-magnetic as well (besides of course the reasons given in the answer).

If the hull of the ISS were substantially ferromagnetic, what kinds of problems would that cause?

Comment: It'd be very heavy.

Comment: And the compass which the shuttle used for navigation, as seen in the fine motion picture "The Core", would have been adversely affected.

Comment: @RoboKaren is right -- first and foremost, it would be too heavy to launch.